# npgsql and Entity Framework code first setup problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, npgsql

The most recent error im getting is

```
ERROR: 42P01: relation "dbo.__MigrationHistory" does not exist
```

but im convinced that this is just because something earlier hasnt been set up properly.

Im currently trying to set up entity framework 4.4 code first to use Npgsql 2.0.12, I have done the following and it seems to atleast be connecting to the database now but giving me the above error when I do context.saveChanges();

- Updated the machine.config for .net 2.0.50727 with;

  < add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" 
  description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server"
  type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
- Added the dlls to the project
- Changed the app.config to look like this;

  ```
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="entityFramework"
        type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,
        EntityFramework, 
        Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
        requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Npgsql"></remove>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
             invariant="Npgsql" 
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" 
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, 
                   Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DataContext" 
           connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=*******;CommandTimeout=20;" 
           providerName="Npgsql" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Data passing in looks like the following

  public class Animal
  {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
      public int NoOfLegs { get; set; }
  }
- Everything else is generic off the shelf set up of contexts

Any help on what I'm doing wrong or tip or tutorials, anything would be helpful. This was just a little proof of concept but I wouldnt mind getting it working.

P.s. sorry for the bad use of code formatting, stack exchange will not let me use it properly for some reason even though its formatted correctly.

Comment: EF will try accessing __MigrationHistory and will catch the exception if this table does not exist. Does the error buble up to your app and causes your app to crash?

Comment: The app is so simple, a console app, it simply has a context made and then does a context.Animals.Add(entity). Its at this point that it crashes, also this is the first time that the initialiser is called due to ef's lazy loading. I believe the error is actually thrown on context.SaveChanges().

Edit: I know migration history is not in the database, I think i may have missed a step in setting up Npgsql that creates these needed tables or do I simply add them in manually?

Comment: The table should be added automatically. Any chance for stack trace?

Comment: I'm currently at work at the moment but will get one for you as soon as possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Error: "Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."

Comment: Stack trace: "at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) at System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) at System.Data.Entity.Database.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c)"

Comment: did you create the database manually or had the EF create the database for you?

Comment: I think I created a new database to work with called 'demo' and then changed 'public' in schema to 'dbo', this was just one of the things said to try when I was trying myself to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you set any initializer? I think the problem here is that an initializer is set to drop and recreate the database if model changes (indicated by System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in the stack trace). However if the database was not originally created by CodeFirst the initializer is not able to figure out whether the model changed and hence the exception. You can also take a look at this blog post http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/ - might be helpful

Comment: Ive read through this and deleted the database so it could be created from scratch and now im getting that the database hasnt been created. Can you tell me if this connection string does what I think it does which is create a database called DataContext on my localhost

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" 
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=DataContext;User Id=postgres;Password=******;CommandTimeout=20;" 
         providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Npgsql doesn't support schema creation, so you have to  create db manually. 
Then to avoid this error add this statement somewhere in your code (in your case it might be on the beginning of Main() function):

```
Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
```

Instead of DataContext use your DbContext implementation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I barely come on Stack overflow signed in. This seems like an interesting solution. I'll mark you as the answer and try it sometime when I fish out the solution I was trying to to do this on. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the previous answer by iwanek.  To be a bit more specific, I like to place the statement in the OnModelCreating override method so that it is always called when the context is created.

```
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
        }
    }
```